# With the attachment_fu rails plugin, is there any way to delete files uploaded to Amazon S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, attachment-fu

Let's say I'm using attachment_fu to attach profile pics to user profiles in a system, with Amazon S3 used as the actual file storage. When users upload new profile pics, I'd like to replace the attached file with the new one. I can do this within my database (i.e. the file metadata) easily, but attachment_fu doesn't seem to provide methods for deleting the files from S3.

Am I missing something, or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out ? I am having the same conundrum.